# SharePoint Online Active Authentication with Two Factor Authentication

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, api, saml, multifactor-authentication

Is there a way to make the implementation suggested by Vitaly Lyamin, working with Two Factor Authentication?

https://docs.microsoft.com/it-it/archive/blogs/sharepointdevelopersupport/sharepoint-online-active-authentication

I have a working implementation of the SharePoint Online Active Authentication suggested by Vitaly Lyamin. The customer activated the Two Factor Authentication on the whole domain and it stopped working. Is there a way to obtain the SPOIDCRL cookie in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it's not possible to obtain the SPOIDCRL cookie in this context when you enable Multi-factor authentication since MFA needs additional verification method.